# Excel page does not load in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, apache-flex, coldfusion, flex4, flex4.5

I am using Flash Builder 4.0 to develop my application. I have a button whereby I click to open a CFM page which generates an Excel sheet.

The code when I click the button in Flex is as follows:

```
openXlsFile(e.target.label, "myexcelexport.cfm", 'TEST');
```

This line of code works fine on Internet Explorer and Mozilla. But it does not work on Google Chrome. Any idea form experts why this is so? Is there any setting that I am missing in Google chrome or something?

Comment: What exactly does happen when you select the button?

Comment: @Dan Bracuk

Actually the openXlsFile is only a function that has the navigatetoURL method that in opens up a cfm page that loads an Excel Sheet.

What I gathered as info the the link below is that navigatetoURL works with IE but not with GoogleChrome. I cannt find any way to do this work. If you have an idea, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been fixed in Google Chrome version 30.0.1599.101

Answer (score 0):

There's currently an issue Chrome is having with its built in Flash (pepperFlash). I'd make sure that's not the cause of your issue.

Details can be found here:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=277210

Comment: thats the very cause of my problem..but I also tried the workaround in the link above..it just does not want to work..getting crazy with this..